# One profile not syncing with BDC

Tags: user-profile-service, user-profile-property, bdc, ups

Somehow a user was created in AD and synced in UPS, the user had a username something like domain\xxx1. The user was then deleted in AD and a new one with the same email/sip was created but with the username domain\xxx2. Since then the account only syncs data with AD but not with any of the BDC models (SQL server views), all other accounts are syncing fine. If we change any data in AD for the broken account it gets propagated to SP fine. I had a look in the FIM client manager and can see that the only connector for the account is AD:

[image]

Whereas for other accounts I can see all the connectors: [image]

I tried to delete the account in central admin and resync but it still only gets data populated from AD. What do I need to do here to make this account sync with AD and our BDC models again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting account in AD and creating new one under same name can be very problematic on Sharepoint; recently in brought one of my farms to complete halt due to SQL locking (it had many fine-grained permissions) We had a ticket with MS open and to solution was very simple user had to be migrated to itself.

Run this command:

```
Move-SPUser -Identity "DOMAIN\JaneDoe" -NewAlias "DOMAIN\JaneDoe
```

Where `"Identity"` and the `"NewAlias"` are exactly the same.